# Stop and play mp3 in mediaplayer

Tags: java, android

I have placed two mp3 songs in raw folder. I have used two buttons to play them. I am calling it as below:

```
public class Songs extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button mBtn1, mBtn2, mBtn3, mBtn4, mBtn5, mBtn6, mBtn7, mBtn8, mBtn9, mBtn10;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    boolean playing = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.songs);

        mBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        mBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        else if (v.getId() == mBtn1.getId()) {

            if (playing) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.pause();
                playing = false;
            } else {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Songs.this, R.raw.chahun);
                mp.start();
                playing = true;
                //  mp.release();
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == mBtn2.getId()) {

            if (playing) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.pause();
                playing = false;
            } else {
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Songs.this, R.raw.sunn);
                mp.start();
                playing = true;
                //  mp.release();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But I think it is giving error while stopping the song. I'm getting error as following:

```
 05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436): java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at com.qwinix.lucia.Songs.onClick(Songs.java:99)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    05-21 11:49:23.006: E/AndroidRuntime(15436):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone please solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Which line is line 99 in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have'nt read the documentation properly that's why you are facing this exception

```
 if (playing) {

     if (mp != null) {
         mp.pause();
     }    
 }
```

If you media is already playing . First of all apply a check for its null condition then don't call stop() method make it pause by calling pause().

**Reason of the exception**

Before calling `stop()` method we have to pause the media first.

**Refer the official docs**

```
public void stop ()
```

**Stops playback after playback has been stopped or paused.**

It is clearly saying has been paused means either you have to pause the play back by calling `Pause()` or it gets stopped after completion.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop%28%29

**Sugesstion** -- One of the goods method for debugging which I really follow is as soon as I am getting exception I started finding all the possible causes for that exception wether I have done all the things correct or not. If not getting solved then I use to read the documents of the methods from the use of which the exception is generated.

Comment: This is working, but i need to click twice on the same button to play the song

Comment: @Aashish J Kumar Why are you using two buttons use a single button for play/pause and apply a single listener.Like see my updated post.

Comment: Not for play/pause. I'm using two different buttons for two different songs. Now when I click on different button then it stops the song, then I need to click on it again to play

Comment: Ya that will happen because the media player object is same. You have to apply a check in your both listener when the song request is coming you have to check that another button is already playing something or not.

Answer (score 1):

you forget to initialize `mp` instance of MediaPlayer . so you will need to initialize `mp` instead of creating new one on Button Click as:

```
if (v.getId() == mBtn1.getId()) {

    if (playing) {
            .....
    } else {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Songs.this, R.raw.chahun);
            ....
    }
} else if (v.getId() == mBtn2.getId()) {

    if (playing) {
            ......
    } else {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Songs.this, R.raw.sunn);
            .....
    }

}

}
```

Comment: This is working, but i need to click twice on the same button to play the song